# How to connect a router behind a proxy server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy

In the residential network provided by my university, we basically are connected behind a proxy server.

In our residential places we are supposed to configure our system with static IP that has been provided to us, and enter our credential to access to the internet.

Now, there are some devices that does not understand these server configuratons (such as google home, amazon echo). For them, I have purchased a new router.

Now, the router detects that my network is configured with static IP and I have configured it likewise. However, With the static IP provided into the router, I can have access to the local servers. But I am not quite sure how to configure it to talk to the server located outside our institution.

Comment: What kind of proxy server is it? That is, where in the OS do you normally configure it?

Comment: I am not quite sure about and I do not have access to that.

Comment: At the residential place we are provided with lan port. And we are ought to configure our ip address in the PC, and in the browser we configure it to use the address of the proxy server. At the begiginning of a session, the server asks us for credentials, and allows us to communicate with rest of the world.